# Error when trying to call a method in a class - x is not a function

Tags: javascript, class

I am trying to call a method outside of its class but i keep getting told this error message:
error: Uncaught TypeError: SmallestIntegerFinder.findSmallestInt is not a function

The code works and it passes the test (codewars) but when i try to call this method to test it myself i get an error.
Does anyone know why this is?

Here is the code

```
    "use strict";
//The class with the method in
class SmallestIntegerFinder {
  findSmallestInt(args) {
    let smallestOne = args[0];
    for(let i = 0; i<args.length ; i++){
      if(args[i]<smallestOne){
        smallestOne = args[i];
      }
    }
    return smallestOne
   }
}
//Here is me trying to call the method
SmallestIntegerFinder.findSmallestInt([34, -345, -1, 100])
```

Comment: You need to create an instance of this class and call the method on it: `const sif = new SmallestIntegerFinder(); sif.findSmallestInt([34, -345, -1, 100]);`

Comment: Beautiful thanks a lot, Are there any scenarios when i do not need to create an instance before i use it?

Comment: If you have [a static method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) then it can be called the way you tried here. A static method belongs *to the class* rather than to the instances.